# Datamaps: how to show popup on mouseover AND customize the mouseover event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, jquery-events, datamaps

I'm using [datamaps](http://datamaps.github.io/) and I costumized the `mouseover` event for my bubbles:

```
map.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-bubble').on('click', function(info) {
  // do something
}).on('mouseover', function(info) {
      // do something else
  }).on('mouseout', function(info) {
      // do something else
  });
```

but I want do my stuff AND show the template popup set with the `popupTemplate` property when I defined the bubbles structure:

```
map_ips.bubbles(
  bubbles,
  {
    popupTemplate: function (geography, data) {
      return '<div class="hoverinfo"><strong>' + data.name + '</strong>' +
        ' <br />' +
        'Country: <strong>' +
        data.country_name +
        '</strong>' +
        '</div>';
     }
   });
```

How can I achieve this? How can I show the popup inside my event listener?
I need to control `mouseover` and `mouseout` events because I want to add a CSS class to some elements into the `mouseover` and I have to remove it with the `mouseout`.

Comment: are you saying that you want to make your own popup in the event listener and not use teh bubble config?

Comment: no sorry, maybe i was unclear! :) When I declare my eventlistener the popup doesn't show up anymore. I want to do my stuff inside my eventlistener AND show the popup that I set up with the popupTemplate. Hope it clarifies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mouse click will not have an issue. So you can do it the way you doing.

```
d3.selectAll('.datamaps-bubble').on('click', function(info) {
  console.log("hello")
  // do something
});
```

Now for hover, the problem is that that dataMaps has registered its mouseover event listener

```
.on('mouseover', function(info) {
  // do something else
});
```

So when you do the above it replaces the dataMap's listener with yours...thus the popup is not visible.

I can think of doing it like this instead:

```
  popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
      doSomethingOnHover();//call your mouse over function in the template
    return '<div class="hoverinfo">'+data.name+'<\div>';
  }

function doSomethingOnHover(){
    console.log("Hovering");
}
```

### Edit

You can add the mouse event to the container on which the datamap is drawn

```
d3.selectAll('.datamaps-bubble').on('click', function(info) {
  console.log("hello")
  // do something
});
//container is the div on which the data map is made.
d3.selectAll('#container').on('mouseout', function(info) {
  console.log("out")
  // do something
});
d3.selectAll('#container').on('mouseover', function(info) {
  console.log("enteredasdasd")
  // do something
});
```

### Edit

You can get the bubble data and which bubble is entered and exited like below:

```
d3.selectAll('#container').on('mouseout', function(info) {
  if (d3.event.target.tagName == "circle"){
   //since you want the bubble only
    console.log(d3.select(d3.event.target).data()[0],"out")
  }
});
d3.selectAll('#container').on('mouseover', function(info) {
  if (d3.event.target.tagName == "circle"){
    //since you want the bubble only
    console.log(d3.select(d3.event.target).data()[0],"over")
  }
});
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uae2re31/2/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cyril, I tried this before but the problem is that I need to have control into the mouseout too, because I add a css class in the mouseover and I have to remove it into the mouseout. I will edit my question with those details!

Comment: I need information contained in the bubble, and I need to know which bubble triggered the mouseover, so I can't attach the listener to che container...

Comment: updated my answer and fiddle Hope this nails it forever!

Comment: thank you SO much for your answer(s) Cyril, it works like a charm! :)

Comment: @Cyril do you know of a way to trigger the popup on click of a specific subunit. I am trying to make the map mobile friendly and would like for when a user taps a state for the popup to show up rather than on hover since mobile doesn't have hover.

Comment: How can i make bubble active on click event, by making hover highlight color stay on bubble after click ?